# How to custom facebook login screen on Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am able to create facebook login function for my Android app. However, when I click the login button, a screen with a progress bar appears to show the authentication progress like the first image. I want to hide the screen behind the progress bar as Pinterest does.

How can I do that ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all you'll want to look into the Facebook SDK to understand how to implement that.

**[Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/)**

As far as the progress bar goes, you have two options:

1. Use the **default android spinner** (Will look different on each device depending on what version of android the user is running)
2. Create a **custom layout** and overlay it on top of the login activity. This option allows you much more flexibility, and will be consistent on all devices. By doing it this way, you can change the transparency level of the black background, as well as setting the exact position and size of that white box.

Hopefully this helps.